# Creating a contacts table for users in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I'm a newbie.. not sure if this is the right place to post this, so please forgive me if it isn't.. i wanted to find out how or what would be the best approach when it comes to making a table for contacts in a database.. Here is what i have :

I have a table for users, this table contains user info like usernames and passwords,etc.. i want to make a program that will allow these users to add contacts,now i don't want to create a contacts table for each user,i would like to have a contacts table which contains all contacts and be able to reference them using an id .. Help please

Comment: This question is way too broad, please ask a specific question or post in a different forum.

Comment: @Victory CodeReview is NOT the place for any questions about unwritten code. Code Review welcomes and offers feedback and improvement suggestions on fully functional code.

Comment: As others have said, a table or users, a table of contacts, and a table that relates one to the other. Also consider having a table of organisations, and a table that relates contacts to organisations. My preference is to set it up so that all contacts MUST belong to at least one organisation. Sometimes that might be something like 'Jim belongs to Project x client group'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a table of users and a table of contacts:

User - UserID, Username, Pw... etc.

Contacts - ContactID, name, phone, info...etc.

For a user to have multiple contacts and for multiple users to have the same contact, you need to create a bridge table to handle the many to many relationship. In this table you'll reference the primary keys (the UserID, and ContactID) from the tables above.

UserContacts - UserID, ContactID. (this can be a composite primary key)

Comment: Thanks Sterls,sorry Im a noob, you'll have to forgive me.. So when querying the contacts of a specific user, i would query the bridge table  ?

Comment: You're not a noob, you got it right! Yes: SELECT ContactID, FROM UserContacts, WHERE UserID = 1; This will return all the contacts that User 1 has.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a table with name of your choice..let's say `Contacts`

You can have this structure

```
ContactId (Primary Key)
ContactName
UserId
Etc..
```

You can start with above structure and improvise..

I recommend this article..
http://www.datanamic.com/support/lt-dez005-introduction-db-modeling.html

Answer (score 0):

Table creation sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE contact(
contact_id VARCHAR(20),
contact_name VARCHAR(20),
user_id VARCHAR(20),
password VARCHAR(20)
);
```

data insertion sample code:

```
INSERT INTO contact(contact_id,contact_name,user_id,password)
VALUES("A123","Daniel","dan2015","password");
```